# How to sell erc20 token

Tags: erc-20

I have deployed contract in Coinbase wallet now how can I swap my erc20 token for tether usd coins or any other crypto

Answer (score 1):

You can go to uniswap dex to exchange your tokens .
https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap

Answer (score 0):

If trying to sell a token you just made up for someone's usdt of value. You likley want to seed a pool with liquidity before trying to get people to exchange their token into it for yours.

Alternatively can try an auction protocol like miso where you can create an auction and ask people to submit the usdt

Obviously you cant create a worthless and illiquid token and just dump it for value, you need to convince a buyer or contract, that it has some.